# Laravel delete action inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach

For each result displayed, I want there to be an associated delete action.

Inside the `foreach` loop I have:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('archive', $alert->id), 'role'=>'form')) }}

<table class="tablesorter table-responsive" id="alerts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="header">ID</th>
        <th class="header">Archive</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($alert->alerts as $alert)
    <tr>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="archive">Archive</button></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('agents/destroy/{id}', 
             array('as' => 'archive', 'uses' => 'AgentsController@postDestroy'));
```

destroy function:

```
public function postDestroy($id)
    {
        $alert  = Alert::find($id);
        $alert->delete();

    }
```

When I `dd($id)`, it returns null, as if it's not picking up the 'id' from the submit button.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML doesn't pass the ID attribute to PHP, I would do what you're trying to do like this:

Route:

```
Route::post('agents/destroy/{id}', array('as' => 'archive', 'uses' => 'blah@postDestroy'));
```

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('archive', $alert->id), 'role'=>'form')) }}
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="archive">Archive</button></td>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller/Model:

```
public function postDestroy($id)
{
    $alert  = Alert::find($id);
    $alert->delete();
}
```

As far as I am aware ID attributes are only really used for selecting elements within the DOM.

**Edit:**

Change the following:

```
<table class="tablesorter table-responsive" id="alerts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="header">ID</th>
            <th class="header">Archive</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($alert->alerts as $alert)
        <tr>
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('archive', $alert->id), 'role'=>'form')) }}
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="archive">Archive</button></td>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Jono20201, this unfortunately doesn't work for multiple results inside the forloop, it returns the last `$alert->id`.

Comment: @Svengali Updated answer with alternative approach.

Comment: Hi Jono20201, unfortunately your amended answer is still referencing only the last alert ID out of the results. Whichever archive button I click on, it's always the last ID that's submitted.

Comment: @Svengali Please post your looping code. I think the problem is the loop, as the code I posted wouldn't just reference that is the loop was right.

Comment: @Svengali Glad we could get that sorted for you! :)